# Best way to save and restore data when using Keras in R

Tags: r, keras

I've (eventually!) managed to set up and train Keras neural networks in R and then use them in the same session to make predictions. I'm now in a position where I need to save the models to use in later sessions. I am aware they can be saved in HDF5 or TF format and there are various options which I am comfortable with. However, my model's independent variables are linked to occurrences of text combinations in documents and there are various other pieces of metadata which are important but aren't processed by Keras. I need to keep all the data together so I am confident that the independent variables match the text in new analyses etc. What is best practice for keeping all parts of the data together?

When I used the simpler nnet package it returned a model file as a simple list object in R. I then made a 'list of lists' containing the model file with all the other data. I could then save that one list as an RDA file and readily import it.

Ideally I want to be able to load one file into R and be able to start work in making predictions with the model. Any suggestions welcome.